# How to add a vertical line between texts in a cell, vba excel

Tags: excel, vba, line

For example, right now I have a cell like this:

[image]

But I want it like this.

[image]

Is it possible in excel VBA?
Thank you!!

Comment: You'll need to switch to a fixed-width font (like courier for example).  As long as the first values are all padded to the same length the pipes should line up.

Answer (score 4):

Use the Text To Columns feature under the Data tab to break this into 2 columns. Then, if you really need a line, select the last column and add a left border.

Answer (score 1):

Is this data all in a single cell?

You will struggle to get it to align correctly, with or without VBA - each character occupies a slightly different width.  **Edited** Well, it may behave better with a fixed-width font, as suggested by Tim Williams, but I still doubt that it will work consistently. (You could only insert spaces and the pipe '|' character, but it won't line up correctly.)

This data belongs in two columns, and multiple rows, with a border between them.